# Adding a controller to edit profiles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am currently writing a small intranet page. It displays employees and their basic details in a list using entity framework to interact with my DB and create an "Employee" class. I am adding logic currently to allow users to edit their profiles. My current problems :

- The forms will only work when navigated to from localhost; using
  PC-NAME/WebAddress results in a 404. What could be causing this ? How can I fix this ?
- The forms are empty; I want to edit a user with profile id=1 for
  example, all of the input boxes are displayed, but they are all empty
  so you need to type in all of their information again. What can I do to add this functionality?
- Access is not restricted to admins and the owner of the profile (where your
  current domain login == the "domainAC" column in my database of users you
  should be permitted to edit the account and not otherwise). Whats the best solution here?

Any help in solving any of these issues would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my current setup/flow of information :

Displaying users using HTML/Razor : (index.cshtml)

```
    <table id="employeeTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Branch</th>
                <th>Phone No.</th>
                <th>Extension</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var prod in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@prod.FullName</td>
                    <td>@prod.Branch</td>
                    <td class="js-phoneNumbers">@prod.PhoneNo</td>
                    <td>@prod.Extension</td>
                    <td>@prod.Email</td>
                    @if (User.IsInRole(@"Admins") || User.Identity.Name == prod.DomainAC)
                    {
                        <td><a href="/home/edit/@prod.Id"  style="color: blue;">edit</a></td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td>User => @User.ToString()</td>   
                    }
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="message" value="@prod.PhoneNo">Message<br>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

HomeController.cs :

```
namespace App1.Controllers
{
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        protected edmxDatabase entities = new edmxDatabase();

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            entities.Dispose(); //what does this do? It was made by default
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var products =
                from p in entities.Employees
                orderby p.Branch descending
                select p;

            return View(products);
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id = -1)
        {
            var employee= new Employee();

            if (employee == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(employee);
        }
   }
}
```

Edit.cshtml :

```
@model App1.Models.Employee

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Employee</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FullName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FullName)
        </div>
        <br/>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Branch)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor( model => model.Branch )
        </div>
        <br/>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <div style="float: left;">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DomainAC)
            </div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DomainAC)
        </div>
        <br/>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNo)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor( model => model.PhoneNo)
        </div>
        <br/>

        <input type="submit" value="Edit Employee details" />

    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: `The forms will only work when navigated to from localhost;` use url helper in index.chtml: `href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Home", new { id = prod.Id })"`

Comment: @YD1m That's one down! Thank you muchly!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The forms will only work when navigated to from localhost;

Use url helper in index.chtml:

```
href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Home", new { id = prod.Id })"
```

> The forms are empty;

You should to fill you model in controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id = -1)
        {
            var employee = new Employee(); // here you should to get user data for editing instead of creating empty model

            if (employee == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(employee);
        }
```

> Access is not restricted to admins and the owner of the profile

The best solution for this case would be to implement custom autorization attribute for CRUD actions. Read more [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs) and after [here](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2011/07/24/writing-your-own-custom-aspnet-mvc-authorize-attributes).

Comment: 2 problems down! Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

For your second question the reason the forms are empty is because you are passing a new instance of the Employee which has no data to show, try this instead for testing.

```
var employee= new Employee { PhoneNo = "12345"};
```

You can restrict access by roles by using the Authorize attribute against a class or a method.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult Edit(int id = -1)
```

Comment: How can I only Authorize is the user is an admin or their current domain login is equal to the DomainAC value in the database for the ID they are trying to edit ?

Answer (score 0):

**Your url**

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Home", new { RID = m.RID })
            OR
 <a href='Edit/@m.RID ' >m.REName</a>
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult Edit(string RID)
        {
            int _RID = 0;
            int.TryParse(RID, out _RID);
            RegisterModel model = new RegisterModel();
            if (_RID > 0)
            {
               var re = (from r in _context.Registrations where r.RID == _RID select r).First();
               model.RID = _RID;
               model.REName = re.REName;
               model.REAddress = re.REAddress;
               model.REPhoneNo = re.REPhoneNo;
                return View(model);
            }
            else
            {
            return View();
            }
        }
```